# Test Classes are giving me 'System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object' Error

Tags: unit-test, controller, custom-controller, null-pointer

So I created a VF Page that utilizes a controller class that I created. Now I need to create the test class for the controller and I am having a hard time with this 'System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object' error. Here is the stack trace of the null error:

```
'Class.BusinessHoursController.BuildVars: line 101, column 1
Class.BusinessHoursController.<init>: line 66, column 1
Class.BusinessHoursControllerTest.bhTest: line 17, column 1'
```

I will display my controller code and then my test class code. Any help would be very appreciated. It errors out my test class when I initialize my controller.

```
/**************************************************************
@class      BusinessHoursController

@description        Controller for the BusinessHoursEdit Page


@version    2016-09-13  HCA.EB
Created.

**************************************************************/



public class BusinessHoursController {

    public string thelabel {get; set;}
    public sObject therecord {get; set;}
    public String day {get; set;}
    public String sunstartHour { get; set; }
    public String sunstartMinute { get; set; }
    public String sunstartPer { get; set; }
    public String sunendHour { get; set; }
    public String sunendMinute { get; set; }
    public String sunendPer { get; set; }
    public String monstartHour { get; set; }
    public String monstartMinute { get; set; }
    public String monstartPer { get; set; }
    public String monendHour { get; set; }
    public String monendMinute { get; set; }
    public String monendPer { get; set; }
    public String tuestartHour { get; set; }
    public String tuestartMinute { get; set; }
    public String tuestartPer { get; set; }
    public String tueendHour { get; set; }
    public String tueendMinute { get; set; }
    public String tueendPer { get; set; }
    public String wedstartHour { get; set; }
    public String wedstartMinute { get; set; }
    public String wedstartPer { get; set; }
    public String wedendHour { get; set; }
    public String wedendMinute { get; set; }
    public String wedendPer { get; set; }
    public String thurstartHour { get; set; }
    public String thurstartMinute { get; set; }
    public String thurstartPer { get; set; }
    public String thurendHour { get; set; }
    public String thurendMinute { get; set; }
    public String thurendPer { get; set; }
    public String fristartHour { get; set; }
    public String fristartMinute { get; set; }
    public String fristartPer { get; set; }
    public String friendHour { get; set; }
    public String friendMinute { get; set; }
    public String friendPer { get; set; }
    public String satstartHour { get; set; }
    public String satstartMinute { get; set; }
    public String satstartPer { get; set; }
    public String satendHour { get; set; }
    public String satendMinute { get; set; }
    public String satendPer { get; set; }
    public Account record { get; set; }

    //  Retrieves the picklist values from the Enterprise DateTime object
public List<SelectOption> getHourOptions()
{
    return getPicklistOptions(Enterprise_DateTime__c.Hour__c.getDescribe());
}
public List<SelectOption> getMinuteOptions()
{
    return getPicklistOptions(Enterprise_DateTime__c.Minute__c.getDescribe());
}
public List<SelectOption> getPeriodOptions()
{
    return getPicklistOptions(Enterprise_DateTime__c.Period__c.getDescribe());
}


public BusinessHoursController(){
        BuildVars(record);
}


public BusinessHoursController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
{
    this.record = (Account)stdController.getRecord();

    BuildVars(this.record);
}

public class BHwrap{
        public String dts {get;set;}
        public String sHr{get;set;}
        public String sMin{get;set;}
        public String sPer{get;set;}
        public String eHr{get;set;}
        public String eMin{get;set;}
        public String ePer{get;set;}

        public BHwrap(String formattedDT){
            this.dts = formattedDT;
        }
    }



    public List<String> days{get;set;}

    public List<BHwrap> bhList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public void BuildVars(Account a){
        List<Account> aq = [Select BHdelimited__c from account where id =:a.id limit 1 ];
        if(aq.size() >0 && aq[0].BHdelimited__c != NULL ){
        List<String> timeSplit = aq[0].BHdelimited__c.split(';');
        integer strCount = 0;


        sunstartHour = timeSplit.get(0);
        sunstartMinute = timeSplit.get(1);
        sunstartPer = timeSplit.get(2).toUpperCase();
        sunendHour = timeSplit.get(3);
        sunendMinute = timeSplit.get(4);
        sunendPer = timeSplit.get(5).toUpperCase();
        monstartHour = timeSplit.get(6);
        monstartMinute = timeSplit.get(7);
        monstartPer = timeSplit.get(8).toUpperCase();
        monendHour = timeSplit.get(9);
        monendMinute = timeSplit.get(10);
        monendPer = timeSplit.get(11).toUpperCase();
        tuestartHour = timeSplit.get(12);
        tuestartMinute = timeSplit.get(13);
        tuestartPer = timeSplit.get(14).toUpperCase();
        tueendHour = timeSplit.get(15);
        tueendMinute = timeSplit.get(16);
        tueendPer = timeSplit.get(17).toUpperCase();
        wedstartHour = timeSplit.get(18);
        wedstartMinute = timeSplit.get(19);
        wedstartPer = timeSplit.get(20).toUpperCase();
        wedendHour = timeSplit.get(21);
        wedendMinute = timeSplit.get(22);
        wedendPer = timeSplit.get(23).toUpperCase();
        thurstartHour = timeSplit.get(24);
        thurstartMinute = timeSplit.get(25);
        thurstartPer = timeSplit.get(26).toUpperCase();
        thurendHour = timeSplit.get(27);
        thurendMinute = timeSplit.get(28);
        thurendPer = timeSplit.get(29).toUpperCase();
        fristartHour = timeSplit.get(30);
        fristartMinute = timeSplit.get(31);
        fristartPer = timeSplit.get(32).toUpperCase();
        friendHour = timeSplit.get(33);
        friendMinute = timeSplit.get(34);
        friendPer = timeSplit.get(35).toUpperCase();
        satstartHour = timeSplit.get(36);
        satstartMinute = timeSplit.get(37);
        satstartPer = timeSplit.get(38).toUpperCase();
        satendHour = timeSplit.get(39);
        satendMinute = timeSplit.get(40);
        satendPer = timeSplit.get(41).toUpperCase();
        }

    }
    public void saveBH()
{
    String datetimeString;
    String dtDelimit;
    days = new List<String>{'Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'};

    //This is for the record

    string sundayHours = sunstartHour + ':' + sunstartMinute + sunstartPer.toLowerCase() == sunendHour + ':' + sunendMinute + sunendPer.toLowerCase() ? ' : Closed | ' : 
                     ': '+sunstartHour + ':' + sunstartMinute + sunstartPer.toLowerCase()+ ' - '+sunendHour + ':' + sunendMinute + sunendPer.toLowerCase()+' | ' ;
    string mondayHours = monstartHour + ':' + monstartMinute + monstartPer.toLowerCase() == monendHour + ':' + monendMinute + monendPer.toLowerCase() ? ' : Closed | ' : 
                     ': '+monstartHour + ':' + monstartMinute + monstartPer.toLowerCase()+ ' - '+monendHour + ':' + monendMinute + monendPer.toLowerCase()+' | ' ;
    string tuesdayHours = tuestartHour + ':' + tuestartMinute + tuestartPer.toLowerCase() == tueendHour + ':' + tueendMinute + tueendPer.toLowerCase() ? ' : Closed | ' : 
                     ': '+tuestartHour + ':' + tuestartMinute + tuestartPer.toLowerCase()+ ' - '+tueendHour + ':' + tueendMinute + tueendPer.toLowerCase()+' | ' ;
    string wednesdayHours = wedstartHour + ':' + wedstartMinute + wedstartPer.toLowerCase() == wedendHour + ':' + wedendMinute + wedendPer.toLowerCase() ? ' : Closed | ' : 
                     ': '+wedstartHour + ':' + wedstartMinute + wedstartPer.toLowerCase()+ ' - '+wedendHour + ':' + wedendMinute + wedendPer.toLowerCase()+' | ' ;
    string thursdayHours = thurstartHour + ':' + thurstartMinute + thurstartPer.toLowerCase() == thurendHour + ':' + thurendMinute + thurendPer.toLowerCase() ? ' : Closed | ' : 
                     ': '+thurstartHour + ':' + thurstartMinute + thurstartPer.toLowerCase()+ ' - '+thurendHour + ':' + thurendMinute + thurendPer.toLowerCase()+' | ' ;
    string fridayHours = fristartHour + ':' + fristartMinute + fristartPer.toLowerCase() == friendHour + ':' + friendMinute + friendPer.toLowerCase() ? ' : Closed | ' : 
                     ': '+fristartHour + ':' + fristartMinute + fristartPer.toLowerCase()+ ' - '+friendHour + ':' + friendMinute + friendPer.toLowerCase()+' | ' ;
    string saturdayHours = satstartHour + ':' + satstartMinute + satstartPer.toLowerCase() == satendHour + ':' + satendMinute + satendPer.toLowerCase() ? ' : Closed | ' : 
                     ': '+satstartHour + ':' + satstartMinute + satstartPer.toLowerCase()+ ' - '+satendHour + ':' + satendMinute + satendPer.toLowerCase()+' | ' ;

    datetimeString = days.get(0)+ sundayHours;
    dtDelimit = sunstartHour + ';' + sunstartMinute +';'+ sunstartPer.toLowerCase()+ ';'+sunendHour + ';' + sunendMinute +';'+ sunendPer.toLowerCase()+';';
    datetimeString += days.get(1)+ mondayHours;
    dtDelimit +=monstartHour + ';' + monstartMinute +';'+ monstartPer.toLowerCase()+ ';'+monendHour + ';' + monendMinute +';'+ monendPer.toLowerCase()+';';
    datetimeString += days.get(2)+ tuesdayHours;
    dtDelimit += tuestartHour + ';' + tuestartMinute +';'+ tuestartPer.toLowerCase()+ ';'+tueendHour + ';' + tueendMinute +';'+ tueendPer.toLowerCase()+';';
    datetimeString += days.get(3)+ wednesdayHours;
    dtDelimit += wedstartHour + ';' + wedstartMinute +';'+ wedstartPer.toLowerCase()+ ';'+wedendHour + ';' + wedendMinute +';'+ wedendPer.toLowerCase()+';';
    datetimeString += days.get(4)+ thursdayHours;
    dtDelimit += thurstartHour + ';' + thurstartMinute +';'+ thurstartPer.toLowerCase()+ ';'+thurendHour + ';' + thurendMinute +';'+ thurendPer.toLowerCase()+';';
    datetimeString += days.get(5)+ fridayHours;
    dtDelimit += fristartHour + ';' + fristartMinute +';'+ fristartPer.toLowerCase()+ ';'+friendHour + ';' + friendMinute +';'+ friendPer.toLowerCase()+';';
    datetimeString += days.get(6)+ saturdayHours ;
    dtDelimit +=satstartHour + ';' + satstartMinute +';'+ satstartPer.toLowerCase()+ ';'+satendHour + ';' + satendMinute +';'+ satendPer.toLowerCase();

    //This is for the wrapper
    system.debug('DateTimeString is: '+ datetimeString);
    system.debug('thelabel is: '+ thelabel);

        record.Business_Hours__c = datetimeString;
        record.BHdelimited__c = dtDelimit;
        checkDateTimes();

// if there are no errors then update the record 
    if (!ApexPages.hasMessages())
    {

        try {
                saveAcct();
            } 
        catch(DmlException excp) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(excp);
        }
    }


}
public PageReference saveAcct()
{
    system.debug('This is the record ID: '+ record.id);
    upsert record;
        PageReference reference = new PageReference('/'+record.id);
        reference.setRedirect( true );
        return reference;   

}


/*******************************************************
        checkDateTimes()

Checks for validation errors in the start/end datetimes
*******************************************************/

public void checkDateTimes() {
    if (record.Business_Hours__c.contains('-Hr-')){
        ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message( ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'There are empty time slots in the Business Hours. You must enter a value.' ) ); 
    } 
    if (record.Business_Hours__c.contains('-Min-')){
        ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message( ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'There are empty time slots in the Business Hours. You must enter a value.' ) );
    }
    if (record.Business_Hours__c.contains('-per-')){
        ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message( ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'There are empty time slots in the Business Hours. You must enter a value.' ) );
    }
}   

 /*******************************************************
        clearHours

Called by the component to clear the current object's
date/time fields
*******************************************************/
public void clearHours()
{

    sunendHour = null;
    monendHour = null;
    tueendHour = null;
    wedendHour = null;
    thurendHour = null;
    friendHour = null;
    satendHour = null;
    sunendMinute = null;
    monendMinute = null;
    tueendMinute = null;
    wedendMinute = null;
    thurendMinute = null;
    friendMinute = null;
    satendMinute = null;
    sunendPer = null;
    monendPer = null;
    tueendPer = null;
    wedendPer = null;
    thurendPer = null;
    friendPer = null;
    satendPer = null;
    sunstartHour = null;
    monstartHour = null;
    tuestartHour = null;
    wedstartHour = null;
    thurstartHour = null;
    fristartHour = null;
    satstartHour = null;
    sunstartMinute = null;
    monstartMinute = null;
    tuestartMinute = null;
    wedstartMinute = null;
    thurstartMinute = null;
    fristartMinute = null;
    satstartMinute = null;
    sunstartPer = null;
    monstartPer = null;
    tuestartPer = null;
    wedstartPer = null;
    thurstartPer = null;
    fristartPer = null;
    satstartPer = null;

}





/*******************************************************
        getPicklistOptions

Utility method used by the methods above to retrieve the picklist values from
the schema for a given field and returns them as a list of select options
*******************************************************/
private List<SelectOption> getPicklistOptions(Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult)
{
    List<SelectOption> sol = new List<SelectOption>();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

    for ( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple )
    {
        sol.add( new SelectOption( f.getLabel(), f.getValue() ) );
    }

    return sol;
}

}
```

Here is my Test Class:

```
/********************************************
@class      BusinessHoursControllerTest

@brief      Test Class for BusinessHoursController


@version    2016-09-26  HCA.EB
Created.
******************************************/
@isTest
private class BusinessHoursControllerTest {

    static testMethod void bhTest(){

        //  Initialize the controller
    BusinessHoursController bhc = new BusinessHoursController();




    /*******************************************************
        Test the setters/getters
    *******************************************************/
    bhc.getHourOptions();
    bhc.getMinuteOptions();
    bhc.getperiodOptions();



    /*******************************************************
        Test saveBH()
    *******************************************************/

    //  Create an Facility
    Account theFacility = TestUtils.createFacility();
    insert theFacility;
    Account a = [Select id,BHdelimited__c from Account WHERE id=:theFacility.id LIMIT 1];
    bhc.days = new List<String>{'Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'};

    bhc.record = a;
    bhc.sunstartHour = '12';
    bhc.sunstartMinute = '12';
    bhc.sunstartPer = 'am';
    bhc.sunendHour = '12';
    bhc.sunendMinute = '12';
    bhc.sunendPer = 'pm';
    bhc.monstartHour= '12';
    bhc.monstartMinute= '12';
    bhc.monstartPer= 'am';
    bhc.monendHour= '12';
    bhc.monendMinute= '12';
    bhc.monendPer= 'am';
    bhc.tuestartHour= '12';
    bhc.tuestartMinute= '12';
    bhc.tuestartPer= 'am';
    bhc.tueendHour= '12';
    bhc.tueendMinute= '12';
    bhc.tueendPer= 'pm';
    bhc.wedstartHour= '12';
    bhc.wedstartMinute= '12';
    bhc.wedstartPer= 'am';
    bhc.wedendHour= '12';
    bhc.wedendMinute= '12';
    bhc.wedendPer= 'pm';
    bhc.thurstartHour= '12';
    bhc.thurstartMinute= '12';
    bhc.thurstartPer= 'am';
    bhc.thurendHour= '12';
    bhc.thurendMinute= '12';
    bhc.thurendPer= 'pm';
    bhc.fristartHour= '12';
    bhc.fristartMinute= '12';
    bhc.fristartPer= 'am';
    bhc.friendHour= '12';
    bhc.friendMinute= '12';
    bhc.friendPer= 'pm';
    bhc.satstartHour= '12';
    bhc.satstartMinute= '12';
    bhc.satstartPer= 'am';
    bhc.satendHour= '12';
    bhc.satendMinute= '12';
    bhc.satendPer= 'pm';

    bhc.saveBH();


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are passing account instance

```
BuildVars(record); // it is still null
```

But you haven't initialized it yet.

So in this query you will get null pointer error

```
List<Account> aq = [Select BHdelimited__c from account where id =:a.id limit 1 ];
```

You can do one thing here create a account record and a standard controller instance it use it

```
Account theFacility = TestUtils.createFacility();
insert theFacility;
ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new ApexPages.StandardControlle(theFacility);
```

and update this to

```
BusinessHoursController bhc = new BusinessHoursController(stdController);
```

Alo I suggest you to check [Apex testing on Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro)